# ¿Cuál es el funcionamiento de yield en Python

Tags: python, yield, generator

Deseo conocer cuál es el funcionamiento de la palabra reservada `yield` en Python,  y en qué casos se puede aplicar.

Por ejemplo si tengo el siguiente código:

```
def contador(max):
    n=0
    while n < max:
            yield n
            n=n+1
```

¿Qué función cumple  el `yield` ahí, ya qué en una función estoy acostumbrado a ver un valor de retorno con la palabra `return`.

Comment: Me fue realmente útil leer el siguiente artículo: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm para comprender lo que preguntas. Te lo dejo como comentario porque no me podido tomar el tiempo en traducirlo

Answer (score 18):

*Editado (la versión anterior tenía errores de concepto)*

Veamos primero un ejemplo:

```
def contador(max):
    n=0
    while n < max:
            yield n
            n=n+1

mycont = contador(5)

for i in mycont:
    print(i)

# print(mycont)
```

El resultado de correr lo anterior es

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

El resultado es el mismo que si, en lugar de `mycont = contador(5)` hubiéramos instanciado una lista: `mycont = [0,1,2,3,4]` o `mycont = range(0,5)`. Pero de hecho lo que ocurre es muy diferente.

Cuando el intérprete Python encuentra una función que incluye un `yield` (o varios), entiende que al llamar esta función no obtendremos un valor devuelto con un `return`, sino que obtendremos un **generador** (*generator*).

Un generador se comporta parecido a una lista, en el sentido que puede ser recorrida con un iterador - la diferencia es que los valores no están almacenados en una colección, sino que se generan "on the fly". Un generador también se puede instanciar con una expresión entre paréntesis, como

```
>>> migen= (x**2 for x in range(1,5))
>>> for i in migen:
>>>     print (i)
1
4
9
16
```

... pero la alternativa con el `yield` es más flexible (aunque algo más difícil de digerir).

En el ejemplo inicial, en la asignación tenemos en `mycont` un generador - el cuerpo de la función `contador()` todavía no corrió. Al ser usado en una iteración, internamente Python llamará `next()` , lo cual disparará la ejecución el cuerpo de la función `contador()` **hasta llegar al primer `yield` - en ese momento retornará el valor (que se asignará a la variable `i`), y la función `contador` quedará en suspenso** (el control pasa al `for` ... ese es el significado
típíco de `yield` : ceder el control de la ejecución a otro hilo o -en este caso- parte del código).

Cuando el iterador vuelva a pedir un valor, se disparará un nuevo `next` sobre el generador, el cual retomará la ejecución hasta llegar al próximo `yield`... y así sucesivamente hasta que la función termine.

Si no te queda claro, conviene insertar prints en medio para verlo bien:

```
def contador(max):
    print("=Dentro de contador - empezando")
    n=0
    while n < max:
        print(f"=Dentro de contador - viene yield con n={n}")
        yield n
        print("=Dentro de contador - retomando después de yield")
        n=n+1
    print("=Dentro de contador - terminando")

print("Instanciando contador") 
mycont = contador(3)
print("Contador instanciado") 

for i in mycont:
    print(f"valor leido del iterador={i}") 
print("Listo")
```

Output:

```
Instanciando contador
Contador instanciado
=Dentro de contador - empezando
=Dentro de contador - viene yield con n=0
valor leido del iterador=0
=Dentro de contador - retomando después de yield
=Dentro de contador - viene yield con n=1
valor leido del iterador=1
=Dentro de contador - retomando después de yield
=Dentro de contador - viene yield con n=2
valor leido del iterador=2
=Dentro de contador - retomando después de yield
=Dentro de contador - terminando
Listo
```

Comment: No me parece raro. Una ventaja que le veo es para que tus programas luzcan como en programación funcional donde puedes declarar listas infinitas cuyos elementos son obtenidos de manera floja (lazy) a demanda del usuario. Por ejemplo, en haskell, puedes definir una lista de todos los números enteros positivos mayores a 0 como `l = [0..]` y luego usar parte de los elementos de esta lista (que se calcularán a demanda) para otras operaciones. Pues sí, la diferencia en el caso de los generadores es que son de 1 solo consumo por elemento.

Comment: No le veo lo raro. Es más, se me hace parecido al de C#

Answer (score 8):

Hay veces que es preferible que una función vaya devolviendo los resultados a medida que los obtiene en vez de devolverlos todos juntos al final de su ejecución. Ése es el cometido de `yield`, el de retornar un valor de una secuencia de valores. Además, devuelve el *"control"* al código llamante, quien decidirá si seguir o no con la ejecución e, incluso, inyectar nuevos datos para modificar el proceso. Es el modo que tiene python de crear **corrutinas**, cuyo potencial se ha visto ampliado muchísimo con las últimas versiones de python y los procesos asíncronos. Es bastante complejo.

Pero volviendo a la pregunta, se puede establecer una analogía entre funciones y objetos. La definición de una función sería como tener una clase con un sólo método, y la ejecución de la función sería como crear instancias de la clase para crear un entorno de ejecución que llamamos "clausura" y que desaparece al finalizar la función. Al usar yield, interrumpimos la ejecución en ese punto, conservando la instancia para su uso posterior, así hasta que hayamos terminado.

Por ejemplo, si declaras un generador así:

```
def contador(max):
    n=0
    while n < max:
            n = yield n
            n=n+1
```

Para crear *"instancias"* sería igual que instanciar objetos:

```
f = contador(100)
g = contador(20)
```

Ambas instancias son independientes, con sus propias clausuras cada una de modo que la ejecución de una no afectará a la otra.

A partir de aquí, podemos operar con estas instancias para crear nuevos iteradores. En módulo `itertools` cuenta con una buena colección de útiles. Por ejemplo, podemos unir los dos generadores en uno sólo, o crear clonar generadores:

```
import itertools

h = itertools.chain(f, g)
h1, h2 = itertools.tee(h)
```

Muchos de los módulos de la librería estándar de python aceptan iteradores y vale la pena revisar cuáles son. Es posible aplicar el constructor `list()` y convertir un interador en una lista, pero es más eficiente procesar valor por valor a medida que se necesiten e ir creando nuevas expresiones generadoras.

Por ejemplo, para obtener sólo los números pares de `h`:

```
pares = (n for n in h if n%2==0)
```

Answer (score 5):

Una sencilla explicación es que `yield` que puede también ser usado para crear generadores, como en este caso que se escribe en una función, la cual usa `yield` y que funciona similar a un `return` pero la diferencia importante es que conserva la iteración, tomando como ejemplo tu script:

```
def contador(max):
    n=0
    while n < max:
          yield n 
          n=n+1
```

Por ejemplo si instanciamos `contador()` e iteramos sobre los valores que se obtienen de la función `contador()` podemos notar que funciona como un `return` pero conserva la iteración:

```
contad = contador(10)
for i in contad:
    print("valor: "+str(i))
```

obtenemos como resultado:

```
valor: 0
valor: 1
valor: 2
valor: 3
valor: 4
valor: 5
valor: 6
valor: 7
valor: 8
valor: 9
```