# un for loop que deberia devolver varias palabras solo da la primera

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios

he definido esta funcion

```
def count_apperances (lis, freq):
    for i in lis:
        score=[]
        if i in freq.keys():
            score.append(freq[i])
        return(score)
```

y al implementar la funcion de este modo me devuelve una lista con un solo valor  [1756], osea cuenta la palabra "I" pero no "movie"

```
count_apperances("I enjoyed this great movie".split(),top_DicPos)
```

donde

```
print(top_DicPos)
{'I': 1756,
 'The': 888,
 'movie': 670, ...}
```

Comment: Me parece que has metido una indentación de más en el return

Answer (score 3):

El problema me parece que esta en el return. El return esta dentro del for lis, es decir va a retornar a la primera iteración por otra parte, debes definie la lista score antes de iniciar el for, quedaría algo así:

```
def count_apperances (lis, freq):
    score=[]
    for i in lis:
        if i in freq.keys():
            score.append(freq[i])
    return(score)
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: perdón, se me olvido decir que si movía el  return fuera del for loop lo que hacia era devolverme el dato de movies  [670] pero no una lista con todos, asi que el error debe estar en otro sitio, pero muchas gracias

Comment: Si señor, es porque estabas definiendo `score=[]` dentro del `for` y en cada iteración se iba a vaciar. fijate que yo lo saque del `for` y le quite la identación al `return(score)` también.

Comment: tienes razon, muchisimas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El error es usar return cuando quieres que te devuelva todos los resultados

return termina la función y devuelve un resultado

```
for i in range(10):
    return i # devolvera solo 0
```

si quieres que cada iteración devuelva un resultado debes usar yield

```
for i in range(10):
    yield i # devolvera 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

tienes mas información sobre yield [aquì](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6048/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-funcionamiento-de-yield-en-python)