# Traducir cadenas usando diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

Estoy programando un traductor y llevo lo siguiente:

```
import re

w2es = {'abla':'Yo', 'dest':'ella', 'lert':'como', 'gufa':'fideos', 'abla lert gufa':'Me gusta comer fideos'}

def Translate(dicty):
    def SubTrans(mo):
        word = mo.group()
        return dicty.get(word.lower(), word)
    return SubTrans


Out = re.sub(r'\w+', Translate(w2es), 'abla lert gufa')
print(Out)
```

Gran parte de eso lo saqué de acá mismo. Cabe aclarar que este traductor es literal, es decir, no es necesario buscar coherencias en las frases ni darles sentido coloquial.

El punto es que para traducir palabras individuales está perfecto, pero tengo una situación y es que algunas palabras juntas tienen un significado distinto al que tiene cuando se traduce cada palabra individualmente, entonces **quisiera saber que puedo hacer para traducir frases y no sus palabras individuales.**

Comment: Examina el texto buscando primero las palabras compuestas. Cuando las hayas traducido, examina el resto para traducir las palabras simples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Introducción

### Cómo se hacen las traducciones

No sé que idioma estás intentando traducir, las traducciónes de palabras se engloba en el **campo del NLP** (Natural Language Processing) este campo está **dominado** por la matemática, concretamente por la estadística y el algebra con técnicas de Machine Learning y Deep Learning (Redes Neuronales) que son las encargadas de hacer traducciones precisas.

[¿Cómo hacer un traductor con Tensorflow?](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention)

### Qué se utiliza en las traducciones

1. Largos **Corpus** de texto, se llama corpus a todo el texto que quiere utilizar en tus
   traducciones.
2. Los Corpus están integrados por **documentos** que son las oraciones que componen dicho Corpus
3. Lo correcto es **utilizar generadores** a la hora de operar con texto, debido a que el texto es más pesado que operaciones númericas y ocupa más memoria RAM, para evitar que colapsar los equipos. Puedes saber más sobre los generadores en [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6048/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-funcionamiento-de-yield-en-python/6054#6054) o en la [documentación oficial](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

Hay más cosas pero con esta intro, puedo generar una explicación

## Explicación del problema

Primero pongo el código explicando las lineas con comentarios y después analizaré lo que hace cada función parte por parte:

```
def ngrams(text, n):
    it_text = iter(text)
    history = []

    while n > 1:
        next_item = next(it_text) #Iteramos con next
        history.append(next_item)
        n -= 1

    for item in it_text:
        history.append(item) 
        yield tuple(history) #Creamos el generador con yield
        del history[0] #Borramos el primer indice de History

def translate(text, dictionary, grams):
    text_splited =text.split(" ") #Separamos cada palabra
    length_sentence = len(text_splited)
    word_count = 0
    
    translated_text = []
    while grams > 0: #Mientras no hayamos recorrido los ngrams ..., 3, 2, 1 seguimos
        text_gram = ngrams(text_splited, grams) #Creamos los ngrams
        grams -= 1
        for gramma in text_gram: 
            length_gramma = len(gramma)
            join_gramma = " ".join(str(word) for word in gramma) #unimos cada gramma
            
            if join_gramma in dictionary: #Si el gramma se encuentra en el diccionario lo traducimos
                translated_text.append(dictionary[join_gramma])
                word_count += length_gramma
        
        if word_count == length_sentence: #Si hemos traducido todos los elementos, retornamos el resultado
            return " ".join(translated_text)
                

dictionary = {'abla':'Yo', 'dest':'ella', 'lert':'como', 'gufa':'fideos', 'abla lert gufa':'Me gusta comer fideos'}
text = "abla lert gufa"

translate(text, dictionary, 3)
```

**Salida:** `'Me gusta comer fideos'`

### Función ngrams

Lo que tu estás buscando, es lo que se conoce en NLP como **grams** o **grammas**. Lo que hace es unir palabras en pares, trios, cuatrios, etc. Estos toman el nombre de bigrams, trigrams, cuatrigrams. El objetivo es el mismo que el tuyo, **identificar conjuntos de palabras que pueden ser traducidos y tienen un significado distinto al que tienen por separado.** Vamos a probarlo por separado:

```
text = "abla lert gufa"
text_splited = text.split(" ")

print("Trigrams: ", list(ngrams(text_splited, 3)))
print("Bigrams: ", list(ngrams(text_splited, 2)))
print("Gram: ", list(ngrams(text_splited, 1)))
```

**Salida:**

```
Trigrams:  [('abla', 'lert', 'gufa')]
Bigrams:  [('abla', 'lert'), ('lert', 'gufa')]
Gram:  [('abla',), ('lert',), ('gufa',)]
```

Esta función lo que hace es devolver un generador, con las palabras agrupadas por **N grammas** donde *N* es el número de palabras unidas que queremos coger. Tener **esta función separada te permitirá hacer pruebas con distintos *N grams*** para mejorar tu traducción, ten en cuenta que si tienes textos muy grandes, a más grande sea la *N* de *N grams* más tiempo de procesamiento te llevará.

### Función translate

La función `translate()` hace uso de la función `ngrams()` para crear los *N grams*, necesita:

- un string
- Un diccionario
- Un entero que es el número *N grams* que quieras formar

**El número de *N grams* es descendente**, es decir si pones que quiere 3 *N grams*. Traducirías los trigrams que encuentre en el diccionario, después probaría con los conjuntos de bigrams, y por último cada palabra individualmente.

## Conclusión

Recalcar lo que dije al principio esta es una resolución a tu problema, pero no es lo recomendado si se quieren conseguir traducciones de calidad. Pero es una buena introducción, para saber como funciona el mundo del NLP y los traductores:

- El uso de generadores
- Distintas terminologías que se usan en NLP
- Qué son los bigrams, trigrams, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias, útil, completa y documentada tu respuesta, el lenguaje en el que estoy trabajando es una lengua nativa de mi estado, y tiene la particularidad de que el mismo pueden que tienen las palabras es el mismo que tiene en español, o sea su traducción es literal, creo que en ese caso está respuesta me viene bien, es cierto que hay palabras que tienen distintos significados, pero creo que a partir de allí puedo defenderme solo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacer un `replace` de manera que procesaremos frases y palabras

```py
def Traducir(string):
    result = string
    for ind in w2es:
        result = result.replace(ind, w2es[ind])

    return result
    
print(Traducir("abla lert gufa"))
```

---

#### respuesta original

Procesaremos cada palabra del string a traducir y haremos un `for` para recorrer cara elemento del diccionario y de coincidir palabras añadiremos la traducción a `result`

```py
w2es = {'abla':'Yo', 'dest':'ella', 'lert':'como', 'gufa':'fideos'}
def Traducir(string):
    string_words = []
    result = ""
    for word in string.split():
        string_words.append(word)
        
    for word in string_words:
        for traductWord in w2es:
            if(word.lower() == traductWord.lower()):
                result += w2es[traductWord] + " "
    
    return result
    
print(Traducir("abla lert gufa"))
```

Comment: Si utilizo el diccionario dado en la pregunta `w2es = {'abla':'Yo', 'dest':'ella', 'lert':'como', 'gufa':'fideos', 'abla lert gufa':'Me gusta comer fideos'` me traduce las palabras individualmente y no me arroja la frase, sería bueno utilizar el metodo comentado por @Candid Moe, dar prioridad a traducir las frases y luego palabra por palabra.